# Scene.cursorProperty() how to bind or add listener

Tags: javafx, scene

I am wondering how to add a listener or bind the cursorProperty() method from the Scene object. I am trying to detect while a scene is being resized by what the present cursor type is.

Comment: I'm also working on similar problem, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest approach, but it helped me to find out what's going on:

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) {

    // .. initialize scene

    addCursorChangeListeners(mainPane);
    scene.cursorProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Cursor>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Cursor> observable, final Cursor oldValue, final Cursor newValue) {
            LOGGER.info("Cursor changed for " + scene + " from: " + oldValue + " to: " + newValue);
        }
    });
}

private void addCursorChangeListeners(final Parent parent) {
    for (final Node child : parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
        child.cursorProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Cursor>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Cursor> observable, final Cursor oldValue, final Cursor newValue) {
                LOGGER.info("Cursor changed for " + child + " from: " + oldValue + " to: " + newValue);
            }
        });
        if (child instanceof Parent) {
            addCursorChangeListeners((Parent) child);
        }
    }
}
```

`Node`s added later are not considered here.